# When creating a next js and tailwind css app , -e or --example Initializes as a TypeScript project instead of Js

Tags: typescript, next.js

**when creating a next js tailwind app I get a project with typescript files which is new,
How To Stop this error from happening?**

I'm using the commands to create a js project and i've done so many times, the commands i use to create a next.js app with tailwind css and with js not typescript.

- npx create-next-app --example with-tailwindcss with-tailwindcss-app

**or**

- npx create-next-app -e with-tailwindcss (then project name)

**Has anybody out there got any ideas to why i keep creating a typescript project?
and how to return to creating js projects free of typescript in next.js?**

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I'd like to know this too, have you found any solution? @Iazurus

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same thing and had to go the other way around. Created a next project without the tailwind and later installed the tailwind. I followed [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs).

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to setup manually, you can use this.

```
git clone "below repository"
```

[nextjs-react-tailwindcss](https://github.com/yhunlu/nextjs-react-tailwindcss)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).